# Dynamically resolve message type and subscribe to topic at runtime in roscpp?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to subscribe to a topic configured at runtime in a C++ node?

For example, is there an API to do the following in roscpp (adapted the code snippet seen [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/36855))?

```
type_name = rostopic.get_topic_type(topic_name, blocking=False)[0]
if type_name:
    type_class = roslib.message.get_message_class(type_name)
    subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(topic_name, type_class, callback)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301480/dynamically-resolve-message-type-and-subscribe-to-topic-at-runtime-in-roscpp-?/) by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2018-08-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
May I suggest a topic change? "subscribe dynamically at runtime" is typically understood to mean: "create subscribers (for a specific msg type) at runtime". You seem to be asking how to create subscribers without knowing the msg type. That would be something else.

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2018-08-24**:
@gvdhoorn I updated the title to hopefully better express the intent of the question. Feel free to improve if you can come up with an even better title!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
I think this is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is possible to do exactly what you want. The package you'll be using is [ros_type_introspection](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_type_introspection) this allows you to dynamically access the meta information of a message and extract the values from any message type.

There is tutorial that shows you how to do exactly what you're asking about [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_type_introspection/Tutorials/GenericTopicSubscriber).

The only limitation of this technique is that you can't automatically create the original ros message type objects, you'd have to code for each one individually.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2018-08-29**:
Thanks for this link! I ended up to only need the `topic_tools::ShapeShifter` for my application. But especially the examples for ros_type_introspection [here](https://github.com/facontidavide/type_introspection_tests) helped me a lot!